# Different res/raw file have the very same ID?

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

I understand all resources within any given namespace (ie com.test.android vs. com.test2.android) will have unique resource id assigned. Now if I call com.test.android within com.test2.android, I find out two different resources got assigned the same resource id thus my getResources().openRawResrouce() is getting the wrong file.

So I have a jar file compiled including res/raw/test.zip as my SDK. Then I included this sdk.jar in a separate project and tried to access this res/raw/test.zip via 
        getInstance().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(com.mycompany.android.R.raw.test)

Yet it returns the wrong file which is com.mycompany.res/drawble-hdpi/lc_launcher.png. I then discovered that's because com.mycompany.android.R.raw.test(res/raw file in my SDK) has the very same ID as com.example.resourcetest.R.raw.ic_launcher

What'd be the appropriate fix?

Thanks,

Lee

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project and check if it's fixed or not.

Comment: That doesn't help. I can see the resource ID is generated always the same by looking at the R.java under "gen" dir. The resources always have the same id assigned. public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class raw {
        public static int hello=0x7f020000;
        public static int hello1=0x7f020001;
        public static int hello2=0x7f020002;
    }
}

Comment: The probably you imported the wrong R package path. having the same id is not a problem, when the packages path are different.

Comment: I thought about that. In my code, I am explicitly compare those two raw resource files with full package path eg com.example2.resourcetest.R.raw.hello and com.example1.android.R.raw.test Both return the same resource id...

Comment: having the same resource id is not the problem. because the place where search happens is not the same for these two IDs!